# Bluemix don't display the Catalog page in Japanese. How can I use Bluemix in Japanese?

Tags: ibm-cloud, display, catalog

I clicked the link of the Catalog on top left of dashboard page, but no items displayed on the Catalog page as below.

[image: There are no items]

I change language setting of web browser from Japanese to US English, Catalog items appeared on the page. I understand that Bluemix supports Japanese language formally, I can not accept this way as a workaround for this issue. 
How can I use Bluemix in Japanese? thank you.

Comment: There was a problem with catalog for languages different than English yesterday. The problem is now resolved and you should be able to see catalog in Japanese. See this page for details http://ibm.biz/bluemixstatus (look for the the October 25, 2016 9:26 AM update on the Events pane.

Answer (score 0):

In general: For such issues you should open a support ticket, not use Stack Overflow.

This seems like an issue with your browser or network connection. In my browser the catalog in Japanese catalog works ok. I tried a couple supported language (by changing the browser preferred language) and reloaded the page. Then the catalog is displayed in that language, though not all service tiles are translated.